# Can you change the folder icon to a picture in that directory?

Tags: raspbian

Like in windows if you place a jpg in a folder called "folder.jpg" and view thumbnail view in the file manager, it will show the jpg image as the folder.  I've tried renaming a jpg to "folder.jpg" and "thumbnail.jpg" and no luck in Raspbian.
I'm coming from a WDLive which does this nicely and I'm trying to duplicate this so I can view my movies from the NAS and select based on the image folder.

1. Is this even possible?
2. Is there a certain size or format?  My movie poster jpgs are 200x300.